# React Context custom middleware instead of Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think about getting rid of `redux` in my applications and make only use of the react context api. Therefor I need to have kind of a middleware to handle HTTP requests (similar to `redux-saga`). What I wrote is the following, but I am not sure if this is really a good approach:

Here is my Context + Reducer:

```js
export const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null,
    token: null,
  };

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(action.payload.user));
            localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(action.payload.token));
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload.user,
                token: action.payload.token
            }
        case "LOGOUT":
            localStorage.clear();
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null,
                token: null
            }
        case "TEST":
            console.log("works")
            break
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const AuthContext = React.createContext()
```

any the middleware i wrote:

```js
export const applyApiMiddleware = dispatch => action => {
    dispatch(action)

    switch (action.type) {
        case "TEST":
            console.log("test")
            dispatch({
                type: 'TEST',
                payload: {
                    data: "foo"
                }
            })
            break
        case "REQUEST_GET_USERS":
            fetch('/users', {
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .then(res => dispatch({
                type: 'REQUEST_GET_USERS_SUCCESS',
                payload: res.data
            }))
            .catch(error => console.warn(error))
            break
        default:
            console.log("DEFAULT")
        //....
    }
}
```

And my app.js:

```js
export const App = (props) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const Routes = props.routes
    const apiDispatch = applyApiMiddleware(dispatch)
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{state, apiDispatch}}>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-4">
                        {props.title}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-4">
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Routes history={history}/>
                {!props.authenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" push /> : ''}
            </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )    
}
```

I now call actions like so:

```
const { apiDispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext)

apiDispatch({
    type: "TEST"
})
```

It seems to work fine and in the way I expected but what are your suggestions? One problem I think about is how could a apply multiple middlewares this way? I also somehow miss something like a `next()` call (which seems to be mandatory for multiple middlewares).

Comment: Note: using context as "state" will force re-renders when the context updates, that cannot be controlled by PureComponent and/or shouldComponentUpdate.
Just know that before you write a too big of an app. gl

Comment: @ThomasWikman thank you for the advise - i currently do not write too large parts due to i am not sure if it's good what i am doing here..